# Could not cast value of type 'UIView' to 'NSArray'

Tags: swift, nsarray, swift3, xcode8, loadnibnamed

How do I get all the views in a Nib file?
I'm trying to get all the views within a `Nib` with:

```
   let objects = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("ViewName", owner: self, options: nil)?[0]  as! NSArray
   let mainView : UIView = objects[0] as! UIView
```

**Though I'm getting this error:**

> Could not cast value of type 'UIView' (0x108080b40) to 'NSArray'
>    (0x105173c58).

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`loadNibNamed` returns array of type `[Any]?` and your are subscript it using `[0]`, means you are accessing the first object of Array. So just remove `[0]`.

```
let objects = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("ViewName", owner: self, options: nil)
```

Second option you can directly initialized `UIView` object.

```
if let mainView : UIView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("ViewName", owner: self, options: nil)?[0] as? UIView {...}
```

Choose which ever solution will solved your error.

Comment: Hi I tried both Nirav D and all the labels in the view are not showing up with their data. Also I'm getting a warning on the first option: Cast from '[Any]?' to unrelated type 'NSArray' always fails.  -- do you need both the as! in the 2nd option.  I tried editing it as it caused an error in Xcode.

Comment: You are not able to access label because have cast it to `UIView`instead of that you need to cast it with your `customView`also i have edited first option there is no need to cast `[Any]?` to nsarray.

Comment: Thanks Nirav for putting me on the right track I have included edits that worked.  Both solutions work.